# Why does sbt assembly of a Spark application lead to "Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am using CDH cluster with Spark 2.1 with Scala 2.11.8.

I use sbt 1.0.2.

While doing `assembly`, I am getting error as

> [error] java.lang.RuntimeException: Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml, org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators

I tried to override the version mismatch using `dependencyOverrides` and `force()`, but neither worked.

### Error message from sbt assembly

```
[error] Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in {file:/D:/Tools/scala_ide/test_workspace/test/NewSp
arkTest/}newsparktest:
[error]    org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml _2.11, _2.12
[error]    org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators _2.11, _2.12
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml, org.scala-lang.
modules:scala-parser-combinators
[error]         at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[error]         at sbt.librarymanagement.ConflictWarning$.processCrossVersioned(ConflictWarning.scala:39)
[error]         at sbt.librarymanagement.ConflictWarning$.apply(ConflictWarning.scala:19)
[error]         at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$ivyBaseSettings$64(Defaults.scala:1971)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:257)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:266)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:257)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:167)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:32)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (*:update) Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml, org.scala-lang.modules:scala-par
ser-combinators
[error] Total time: 413 s, completed Oct 12, 2017 3:28:02 AM
```

### build.sbt

```
name := "newtest"
version := "0.0.2"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8" 

sbtPlugin := true

val sparkVersion = "2.1.0"

mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("com.testpackage.sq.newsparktest")

assemblyJarName in assembly := "newtest.jar"


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.1.0" % "provided",
  "com.databricks" % "spark-avro_2.11" % "3.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.11" % "2.1.0" % "provided")


libraryDependencies +=
     "log4j" % "log4j" % "1.2.15" excludeAll(
       ExclusionRule(organization = "com.sun.jdmk"),
       ExclusionRule(organization = "com.sun.jmx"),
       ExclusionRule(organization = "javax.jms")
     )

resolvers += "SparkPackages" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/"
resolvers += Resolver.url("bintray-sbt-plugins", url("http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

### plugins.sbt

```
dependencyOverrides += ("org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-xml_2.11" % "1.0.4")
dependencyOverrides += ("org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-parser-combinators_2.11" % "1.0.4")
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.5")
resolvers += Resolver.url("bintray-sbt-plugins", url("https://dl.bintray.com/eed3si9n/sbt-plugins/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

Comment: Please accept the answer at your earliest convenience. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** Remove `sbtPlugin := true` from `build.sbt` (that is for sbt plugins not applications).

You should also remove `dependencyOverrides` from `plugins.sbt`.

You should change `spark-core_2.11` and the other Spark dependencies in `libraryDependencies` to be as follows:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0" % "provided"
```

The change is to use `%%` (= two percent signs) and remove the version of Scala from the middle part of a dependency, e.g. `spark-core` above.

Comment: Does provided also applies for when deploying to Yarn ?

Comment: Yes. Moreover, a YARN cluster is usually a part of a Hadoop distribution (CDH, HDP, MapR) and comes with a custom `spark-submit` to take care of Spark dependencies and more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am about to move on yarn and I was indeed thinking about it. Although in your answer what I do not see is spark libraries. Why spark libraries would be on yarn. Yearn was not build for spark. Any java app can run on it. To run this app, it needs all its dependencies in all nodes of the cluster. In the case of yarn, spark is just an app like any other. Are you saying that the full spark libraries (the version that you need) is already distributed all over your cluster whenever you have a valid yarn cluster in place ? If so how so ?

Comment: My intuition was to to package it all including spark libraries themselves when it comes to yarn or mesos. While on a stand-alone cluster I would use provided.

Comment: @MaatDeamon Your questions begs for a separate question on SO with `yarn` and `apache-spark` tags. We're drifting away from the OP's question, aren't we?